# Clear an observable value on logout

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to clear an observable value on the logout function.
Below is the observable in my service class

```
cacheSettingsData$: Observable<any>;
```

this is the method where the value is getting assigned.

```
public getUserSettings() {
    if (!this.cacheSettingsData$) {
      this.cacheSettingsData$ = this.requestUserSettings();
      this.userSettings = this.cacheSettingsData$;
    }
    return this.cacheSettingsData$;
  }
```

so the problem is when the user logs out the cacheSettingsData$ observable doesn't clear and if another user logs in it shows the same old data.

How can I clear the data in the observable so that it loads the data again on login?

Comment: Try `delete this.cacheSettingsData$` and `delete this.userSettings` in the logout handler function.

Comment: Make sure your function requestUserSettings return new observable

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you mean by "clear observable". You can just reassign `cacheSettingsData$` to an empty Observable:

```
this.cacheSettingsData$ = EMPTY;
```

But this will affect only new observers.

If you want to notify all subscribed observers you can merge a Subject into the chain:

```
loggedOut$ = new Subject();
...

this.cacheSettingsData$ = merge(
  this.requestUserSettings(),
  loggedOut$,
);
```

Then you can use it as `loggedOut$.next(null)` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear observable on log-out event handler.

```
this.cacheSettingsData$ = of([]);
```